# on my code, materializecss class "card-reveal" is not working

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Here is my materializecss framework using html code below. This is first time I tried to implement card.

I don't know why card-reveal class is not working. please help me to active card-reveal. Thank you.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>materialize cards</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="blue darken-2">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper container">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">MyMaterializecss</a>

      <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col l4">
        <div class="card-panel pink white-text">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col l4">
        <div class="card-panel">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            <img class="activator" src="shuvonet-revised-front-end-03.png">
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
            <p><a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-reveal">
            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
            <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer blue darken-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer-copyright">
        Copyright &copy; 2016 Jarin | All rights reserved.
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @TimOgilvy snippet is posted.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is good to import `js` files at the end of the body to reduce page load time.

And also, import `jQuery` before importing `materialize.js`

**Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/2h8wp527/1/)**

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>materialize cards</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="blue darken-2">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper container">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">MyMaterializecss</a>

      <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col l4">
        <div class="card-panel pink white-text">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col l4">
        <div class="card-panel">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            <img class="activator" src="shuvonet-revised-front-end-03.png">
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
            <p><a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-reveal">
            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
            <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer blue darken-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer-copyright">
        Copyright &copy; 2016 Jarin | All rights reserved.
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is : (css in script tags)

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css"></script>`

Replace it with :

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>`

There you go:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>materialize cards</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="blue darken-2">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper container">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">MyMaterializecss</a>

      <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col 14">
        <div class="card-panel pink white-text">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col 14">
        <div class="card-panel">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            <img class="activator" src="shuvonet-revised-front-end-03.png">
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
            <p><a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-reveal">
            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
            <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer blue darken-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer-copyright">
        Copyright &copy; 2016 Jarin | All rights reserved.
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry for that silly mistake. but not yet working. pls check it playing the code. thank you.

Comment: Yes. Its working. thank you. script tag about html, is it needed? @Ani Menon

Comment: @JobaidaJarin No thats not needed thats added by the SO snippet. (for jQuery).